# How to achieve specific Form style in MenuBarExtra with SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I am trying to achieve a specific Form style in SwiftUI, but I am struggling to get the results I am looking for. The code I am using is below:

```
struct MyApp: App {
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        
        MenuBarExtra("Internet Service", systemImage: "network") {
            InternetInfo()
        }
        .menuBarExtraStyle(.window)

    }
}

struct InternetInfo: View {
    @State var usage: Double = 230.0
    @State var quota: Double = 60.0

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            
            Gauge(value: usage, in: 0...1000) {
                Text("Used Bandwidth")
            } currentValueLabel: {
                Text("\(Int(usage)) GB").font(.caption)
            }
            
            Gauge(value: quota, in: 0...100) {
                Text("Disk Quota")
            } currentValueLabel: {
                Text("\(Int(quota)) GB").font(.caption)
            }
            
        }
        .gaugeStyle(.accessoryLinearCapacity)
        .formStyle(.grouped)
    }
}
```

I am trying to get the following results:

[image]

You will notice that there is a border around the form being shown.

But instead I am getting this:

[image]

In this image, I am not getting any sort of border around my form.

Is there something I'm missing? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: It’s probably a custom view rather than a default Form. May not even be SwiftUI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure I understand exactly what you want but using `GroupBox` instead of `Form` will result in something that is close anyway

```
GroupBox {
    Gauge(value: usage, in: 0...1000) {
        Text("Used Bandwidth")
    } currentValueLabel: {
        Text("\(Int(usage)) GB").font(.caption)
    }
    .padding(16)

    Gauge(value: quota, in: 0...100) {
        Text("Disk Quota")
    } currentValueLabel: {
        Text("\(Int(quota)) GB").font(.caption)
    }
    .padding(16)
}
.gaugeStyle(.accessoryLinearCapacity)
.padding(32)
```